Decrypting multiple files quicker with gpg
The pass program is a command line utility to store passwords plus free form extra data in small files encrypted with gpg. It provides a grep sub-command in particular to find passwords by the extra data.
But this grep sub-command is painfully slow on my machine. I have nearly 200 passwords stored and internally each file is decrypted with gpg like so (without the time in front, of course):
% time gpg -d --quiet --yes --compress-algo=none --no-encrypt-to stackoverflow.gpg
  the password output
user=0,000 sys=0,006 wall=0,382 (1,61)

Wall time is nearly 0.4 seconds which adds up to around 1 minute to grep through all files.
The gpg-agent is running and I have this version:

gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27

Two suspicions why this is slow:

Startup of gpg and communication with gpg-agent is slow, supported by the fact that user+sys times are small in comparison.
gpg-agent is slow, supported by the fact that after a pass grep run its cumulative CPU time is increased by 60 seconds, nicely matching the total time of the complete run.

Together, both point to gpg-agent, though I have no idea why the agent should be so slow. With ps I see it running as
/bin/gpg-agent --sh --daemon

Can someone shed some light on whether ~ 0.3 CPU seconds is reasonable for the agent per file or whether there is a way to improve this?
EDIT: Further Findings
Attaching strace to the agent, I find this:
20200 14:57:03.701648 getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={tv_sec=133, tv_usec=890780}, ru_stime={tv_sec=0, tv_usec=99975}, ...}) = 0
20200 14:57:03.701666 clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, {tv_sec=133, tv_nsec=990762100}) = 0
20200 14:57:04.063523 getpid()          = 18035

where we have 360ms between clock_gettime and the getpid call.
And with ltrace:
20472 15:04:55.035574 strlen("my-password-here")                                                      = 10
20472 15:04:55.035641 gcry_kdf_derive(0x7d884b82c008, 10, 19, 2)                                = 0
20472 15:04:55.394727 gcry_cipher_setkey(0x7d884b82cbc0, 0x7d884b82c030, 16, 0x7d884b83c000)    = 0

So gcry_kdf_derive takes 360ms. Whatever it does, can I get it to cache its result for a few seconds with some config setting. (... goes fetching the source code).

Seems related: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/219106 But why would the agent derive some key in this scenario for each call? Should a key derivation function not only be called when a new key is needed?

KDF's are Key Derivation Functions that convert a password into a cryptographic key. It needs this to decrypt your passwords. To keep passwords from being guessed they are all intentionally slow when first designed.
Generally GPG will cache a private key once you've entered the password for it or used it recently.  It think it only does this on a per-key basis though.  If these keys are really encrypted with the same key from the KDF (and not incorporating unique information from the key itself in each KDF call) then you could keep the results from the KDF probably only by writing your own code from gcrypt up.  The alternative would be using a master key in GPG that's unlocked with a single KDF and then used to decrypt the individual keys and passwords while it's cached.
I have no idea if either of these work with your system.

"Generally GPG will cache a private key once you've entered the password for it or used it recently." This is what seems to not being done. Even if a new key would be used to encrypt each password file, I would expect a speedup if I run pass grep twice in a row. But this is not the case.

Are your passwords encrypted with a password directly or with a GPG key on the chain unlocked with a password?  The latter should be cached, the former won't be because it has no reason to think you want to.

Hmm, actually I don't know. I started using gpg quite naively with gpg --quick-gen-key and that sufficed to get pass going. I also tried --full-gen-key though mostly with defaults, same slowness. Afaiu, this generated a key and I assumed it will be used for the files, unlocked by the "master" password I used with the key generation. I'll read more about the exact gpg function, but wouldn't mind a reading hint or keyword to look for.

That sounds like it was done correctly.  Depending on the version you might have ended up with an obscure key type if you take the gpg defaults.  If you're punching in your password to gpg once to unlock that key you generated instead of feeding it in individually to decrypt each file then it should be working correctly already, provided you have gpg-agent working.  I have signing systems that sign dozens of files with a cached key like this in rapid succession.  It does feel like these signing are slower than some of the other signing types involved though. Maybe there's a weakness in gpg

Weird. OK. Maybe I try some other key type. Currently I have
`pub   rsa3072 2024-06-14 [SC] ...
sub   rsa3072 2024-06-14 [E]

Then your defaults are good.  gpg used to really like DSA and Elgamal
